# Aglio - API Blueprint - Path variables not showing up

Tags: rest, apiblueprint, aglio

I have an API blueprint which goes something like this:

```
## Organization Users [/organizations/{id}/Users]

         + Parameters

            + id (string, required) - path variable, id of the organization.


some text was here.

### Get Org Users [GET]

some text was here.

+ Request (application/json)
```

When I run Aglio with something akin to:

```
aglio --theme-variables streak  -i AppServices/Organizations.apib -o Build/AppServices.html
```

I get the output like:
[image: No path variable]

Notice that the path variables are simply not present.

Other facts:

1. No warning is shown by aglio while generating the output
2. The API blueprint validates fine.
3. I tried all the themes aglio has to offer, same result.

Comment: posted this in aglio's issues as well: https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio/issues/327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kyle Fuller (https://github.com/kylef) answered my question on the Aglio's github issues:

The parameters section is incorrectly intended and thus showing up as raw markdown description.

I think you want something like:

```
## Organization Users [/organizations/{id}/Users]

+ Parameters
    + id (string, required) - path variable, id of the organization.

some text was here.

### Get Org Users [GET]

some text was here.

+ Request (application/json)
```